# Can't produce a LaTeX file, error says I am missing 'ulem.sty'

Tags: ulem, org-mode, dvipng

I have been using org mode on my Manjaro system for more than two years, but after the latest update to the LaTeX repos, I can't seem to export org files to pdf or preview latex fragments.

The error I get whenever I try to preview my LaTeX is:

```
 org-compile-file: File "/tmp/orgtexNnJFiR.dvi" wasn’t producedPlease
 adjust ‘dvipng’ part of ‘org-preview-latex-process-alist’.
```

I tried [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/57917/38074), didn't work.

I checked basic exporting from org to pdf. I got the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `ulem.sty' not found.
```

Which is weird, since when I search for the file using `pacman -F ulem.sty`, I get:

```
extra/texlive-core 2021.58710-2 (texlive-most)
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty
```

Did someone experience that?

Comment: Is the file `/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty` there (try `ls`)? Have you tried, reinstallation of `texlive-most` resp. `texlive-core` (maybe the installation is broken for some reason)? I don't use Manjaro. But maybe even try installing `texlive-full`. Than you should really have everything.

Comment: The [tag:org-mode] tag is an emacs thing.  But the rest of your post suggests that you're talking about something else.  What is org?

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed it, so posting the solution for other confused org-mode users, here's what i've done to fix this.

My texlive installation originated from the Arch packages. After investigating [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/TeX_Live), I decided to install it natively.

After some 5 hours of installation and adding the required directories to the PATH, it works like a charm.

Comment: Installing TL natively from TUG is in generally preferable to installing it through a Linux package manager. Besides other problems like yours, the latter are almost never up-to-date versions and might lack newer packages or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you found a solution. However, I was able to fix it with

```
sudo pacman -Fy
pacman -F ulem.sty
pamac install texlive-plaingeneric
```

The first command is important, since the location of ulem.sty has changed, from texlive-core to texlive-plaingeneric. I also upgraded the system before all that, with "pamac update".

Sorry for carelessly mixing pacman and pamac...

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04, I fixed this error by installing package `texlive-plain-generic`.

```
sudo apt install texlive-plain-generic
```